# How to handle 500 error code using retrieve in webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I've read quite a few documentations and other stackoverflow questions regarding this matter but I can't seem to get my code working.

So essentially I have a WebClient making a POST request.

- IF the response status is 200, then I make another call to another endpoint using a different WebClient. After second webclient call, return a string.
- ELSE I just return a String from the method e.g. "failed to create order.".

Simple enough. (this is all done in a seperate thread fyi, not the main thread.)

But I've noticed that if i do get back a 500 error code, WebClient throws an exception. What I want to do is capture the exception and handle that gracefully and return a String like "Error calling first endpoint etc."

This is what I have so far:

```
private String generateOrder(ImportedOrderDetails importedOrderDetails)
   {
    
      Order requestBody = generateRequestBody(importedOrderDetails);
      OrderResponse responseForCreatingOrder = orderWebClient()
                                                       .post()
                                                       .body(Mono.just(requestBody), Order.class)
                                                       .retrieve()
                                                       .bodyToMono(OrderResponse.class)
                                                       .block();

      
      if (responseForCreatingOrder.getResponseStatus().equals(SUCCESS))
      {...other call using different webclient}
      else{ return "Error creating order."}
```

This works fine when the response status is 200 but when its 500 it blows up.
OrderResponse is a custom object. `orderWebClient()` is just a method that returns a prebuilt WebClient containing the baseUrl and headers etc.

I came across this:
[Spring WebClient - How to handle error scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304827/spring-webclient-how-to-handle-error-scenarios) I did try implementing it but couldn't figure out where to put the block method since I kept on getting the following:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.lang.Exception
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:393)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1680)
```

I had to edit my code a bit to try and implement the answer to that question:

```
   private Mono<? extends Throwable> handleError(String message) {
      log.error("====---"+message);
      return Mono.error(Exception::new);
   }

   private String generateOrder(ImportedOrderDetails importedOrderDetails)
   {
      Order requestBody = generateRequestBody(importedOrderDetails);
      Mono<OrderResponse> responseForCreatingDemo = orderWebClient()
                                                       .post()
                                                       .body(Mono.just(requestBody), Order.class)
                                                       .retrieve()
                                                       .onStatus(
                                                          (HttpStatus::is5xxServerError),
                                                          (it -> handleError(it.statusCode().getReasonPhrase()))
                                                       )
                                                       .bodyToMono(OrderResponse.class);


      
      System.out.println("-=-"+responseForCreatingDemo);
      if (responseForCreatingOrder != null && responseForCreatingOrder.block().getHeader().getResponseStatus().equals(SUCCESS)){...}
```

The error was coming from the `.block` part in the if condition. I believe this is something pretty trivial and missing the big picture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post `OrderResponse` class?

Comment: I'm away from my laptop but it's just essentially a simple pojo class that has Json annotations like `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` , `@JsonProperty` etc from the jackson lib.

Comment: If you’re calling `block()` just use `RestTemplate`. You’re breaking the reactive chain anyway - there’s very little point to the additional complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two kinds of statuses:

1. Http status, defined by the protocol itself (see [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status))
2. Something specific to the application you're working on, encapsulated into the `OrderResponse` class.

So you have to handle two "errors" instead of one, *one* of the possible solutions might look like

```java
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(OrderResponse.class)
// 4xx, 5xx errors and return "Unable to create order" String instead
.onErrorContinue(WebClientResponseException.class, (ex, v) -> 
    Mono.just("Unable to create order"))
// if application specific status is not "ok" return "Unable to create order"
.map(it -> it.ok ? "Ok response" : "Unable to create order")
.block();
```

*Please note that this code sample ignores exception and does not even log it*